# Air conditioning not working at all after fan resistor replaced

Tags: hyundai, air, getz

I have a 2011 Hyundai Getz. The aircon was only working on high speed, so I had the fan resistor replaced by an aircon mechanic. less than two weeks later the aircon wouldn't turn on at all when I first got in the car, but would kick in after I'd been driving a few minutes. Now the aircon is just not working at all, on any setting. No fan, no cool air, no noise, nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you had the aircon system checked - it may have lost refrigerant and needs topping up - a low refrigerant level can cause slow starting...

Comment: @Solar Mike: I doubt it has something to do with the ac. Sounds like the interior ventilation fan is not working.

Comment: @Daniel doubt all you want, still worth checking...

Comment: @Solar Mike: But if there is "no fan" and the resistor was just replaced this has nothing to do with ac, and op is just using the wrong problem description.

Comment: @Daniel in the Q, the OP describes the A/C as kicking in after a few minutes... So, as I said still worth checking...

Comment: @Daniel the best way to get a correct answer is first to know and ask the correct question...

Comment: @Solar Mike: Yes, I suspect when OP writes of "AC" kicking in she means the fan starts to blow, which reeks of a slack joint. Maybe OP can clarify?

Comment: @Emily when you talk about the AC not working, do you mean the fan does not blow, or do you get airflow and it just isn´t cooled?

Comment: @Daniel the fan doesn't blow. Not even on highest speed, which is why I didn't think it was the resistor, but it is very possible (maybe even likely) that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check the resistor, maybe it is not plugged in right or the contacts are corroded. Maybe it is faulty. Those resistors get hot, so a bad soldering point could get loose after some usage.
- Check the fuses.